# How do I convert (universal datetime) string to datetime in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying the following statement and it throws an error:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 06 May 2015 11:08:00 PDT", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT", null)
```

I even tried this and it did not work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 06 May 2015 11:08:00 PDT", "R", null)
```

Comment: Which error did it throw?

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"